# Decrypting forms authentication token (AES, SHA1) in node js

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, authentication, cryptography

Has anyone had luck decrypting a .NET forms authentication generated cookie in node js using the crypto library?

I'm using AES for encryption and SHA1 for validation in .NET forms authentication mechanism.

I was wondering if someone had this problem before and solved it?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/xsp/system/Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs#21ad8e6b6f1681a2

Answer (score 0):

I played with this and made the following code for Node.js:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');

function hash(password) {
  // your validation key from web.config + 00 at the end
  var buf = new Buffer('...00', 'hex');
  var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', buf);
  // convert password from utf8 to UTF16
  var pass = iconv.encode(password, 'utf16le');
  hmac.update(pass);
  return hmac.digest('base64');
}

console.log(hash('test'));
```

Use it to compare hashes from your database.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on web.config settings.

You can see the source code of Encryp and Decrypt here with all the different possibilities (Framework20SP1, Framework20SP2, etc)

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs

For example, on Framework20SP1 the cookie looks like: Enc(IV+SerializedTicket+Modifier)+HMAC(Enc(IV+SerializedTicket+Modifier))